# Code to produce edges of a triangle

Tags: c++, geometry, trigonometry

I am using some code I found that tests two triangles for intersection. The portion of the code I am having trouble with is:

```
/*tr_tri_intersect3D - C1 is a vertex of triangle A. P1,P2 are the two edges originating from this vertex.
D1 is a vertex of triangle B. P1,P2 are the two edges originating from this vertex.
Returns zero for disjoint triangles and non-zero for intersection.*/

int tr_tri_intersect3D (double *C1, double *P1, double *P2,
double *D1, double *Q1, double *Q2);
```

What I don't understand is, if I have the three vertices of 2 triangles, what do I need to do to produce the input for this function?

The full source code can be found at:

[Triangle Triangle Code](http://webee.technion.ac.il/cgm/Computer-Graphics-Multimedia/Software/TriangleIntersection/code.cpp)

```
The source code had a test function, it was:

for (i = 0; i<10000; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<3; j++){
            for (k = 0; k<3; k++){
                PS[i][j][k] = drand48();
                QS[i][j][k] = drand48();
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j<2; j++){
            for (k = 0; k<3; k++){
                EPS[i][j][k] = PS[i][j + 1][k] - PS[i][0][k];
                EQS[i][j][k] = QS[i][j + 1][k] - PS[i][0][k];
            }
        }
    }
    double sum = 0;
    int t0 = clock();
    int sums[100] = { 0 };
    for (j = 0; j<1000; j++)
        for (i = 0; i<10000; i++){
        int res = tr_tri_intersect3D(PS[i][0], EPS[i][0], EPS[i][1],
            QS[j][0], EQS[j][0], EQS[j][1]);
        sums[res]++;
        }
```

if that help.

Comment: As in, how do you call the function? I would assume pass your six verticies that you already have to it.

Comment: From the comments in the code it seemed like it was asking me for edges in P1, P2, Q1, and Q2. Is that no different from a vertex?

Comment: An edge is made by two vertices. You can't pass an edge, as there is no such thing as an edge, just two points which make a line which we call an edge.

Comment: @David Yeah, that's what I thought. I just put the test code that was in the file in my post, does that help?

Comment: Not at all. Nonetheless, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample code it seems like what it mean by an edge is the vector from the originating vertex to the end vertex. 
In the case of a triangle with three vertices C1, C2, C3, the two input edges would be P1 = C2-C1, P2=C3-C1

Comment: Okay, awesome. The algorithm doesn't seem to work right with every combination of triangles, but you were right about how to feed it input.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the test code, it looks like C and D are two [3][3] array of 9 doubles, which are points 1, 2 and 3 and their 3D x,y,z coordinates.

P1 and P2 are the x,y,z distances of points 2 and 3 from point 1 in triangle C, and Q1 and Q2 are the x,y,z distances of points 2 and 3 of triangle D from point 1.  (Edit: byebyebryan said it better, this is the x,y,z vector from point 1 to points 2 and 3).  These two are both an array of [3] doubles (basically, bounding box info).

No idea why the Ps and Qs are not computed inside the function, unless the vars also serve to hold return values somehow.